# reactjs, how to hide menu before login

Tags: reactjs

I have menu horizontal from ant design, how can i hide menu component in login page and display after user access any one of the protected route.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to use switch from react-router-dom.
- Extract the Menu code and make it as a separate component (not needed
  but it will be easy to change layout at any point of time in future)
  And then wrap the Menu component around `<Component />` inside protected
  route...
- Then inside Menu component you can use this.props.children to load
  hello component.

Here is sample of Code (I just named menu component as layout)..Just add your new private routes, it gonna display with menu. If it is public route it wont display menu

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kprtzd

Comment: You can upvote if you are satisfied with the answer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a booelan variable in your state and set it true, if the user is logged in.

```
state = { isLoggedIn: false }
```

Then in your routes user ternary operator to check if the use is logged in.

```
{ this.state.isLoggedIn && <PrivateRoute   ... /> }
```

Comment: After adding this also my login page consists of menu item, which i shouldn't want.can you  help me how can i hide menu  on login page and display on other pages

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dxrpk6,  now on the login page there is menu   called hello, which i dont want to display there, but it should come after i login

Comment: I dont see any changes, can you tell me where you have updated.

Comment: did you see the changes?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the changes. but this will not survive my purpose, the problem i am facing with this is, i am calling from a state without menu, so after  login it is  landing on private component page with out menu, if i reload the page then it is showing the menu with private component page