# How to switch between tabs or navigation menu using dynamic routing in react js?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am quite new to ReactJS and I am really stuck in the process of routing. There are n numbers of methods on routing and i am really confused where should i place the links and the routes and is there any need of mounting a component in this or not and if once i am able to get the data so is routing the efficient way to do it in a dynamic environment?
i have an existing templates of ant design!

Index.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "antd/dist/antd.css";
    import "./index.css";
    import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router";
    import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon } from "antd";
    import Example from "./Components/allSubCount";
    const { SubMenu } = Menu;
    const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Layout>
         <Header className="header">
           <div className="logo" />
             <Menu
              theme="dark"
              mode="horizontal"
              defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]}
              style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}
             />
          </Header>
             <Layout>
                 <Sider width={200} style={{ background: "#fff" }}>
                  <Menu
                   mode="inline"
                   defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
                   defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
                   style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
                 >
                      <SubMenu
                       key="sub1"
                       title={
                       <span>
                            <Icon type="user" />
                             Dashboard
                       </span>
                       }
                  >
                                <Menu.Item key="1">Sub Graph</Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item key="2">Int Graph</Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item key="3">PO Graph</Menu.Item>
                      </SubMenu>

                             <Menu.Item key="4">
                                <span>
                                     <Icon type="user" />
                                      Marketers
                                </span>
                             </Menu.Item>
                             <Menu.Item key="5">
                                 <span>
                                      <Icon type="user" />
                                      Consultants
                                 </span>
                             </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
             </Sider>
          <Layout style={{ padding: "0 24px 24px" }}>
                   <Content
                    style={{
                    background: "#fff",
                    padding: 24,
                    margin: 24,
                    minHeight: 280
                    }}
                   >
                  <Example />
                  </Content>
            </Layout>
          </Layout>
       </Layout>,
       document.getElementById("container")
       );
```

Comment: This may be helpful - https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

**Refer dis answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053141/6150566

I have included sample code in the link that was provided in the above answer. However, you don't have to use protected routes if you don't prefer to. But it is better to isolate route and app layout logic.